# How to properly link bootstrap scripts under wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a WP theme using Bootstrap 5 and I have encountered a problem that I cannot solve. I would like to place the bootstrap files directly into the theme files. I have successfully done this with the `.css` files, but I am having problems with the `.js` files. Do any of you perhaps have an idea what I am doing wrong that elements like `navbar-toggler` are not working? By including the js file `<script src="_TEMP0_@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` in the theme using the CDN everything works. When I do it manually it no longer works.

Here is an excerpt from my `functions.php` file:

```
function imago_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet', array(), null );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'imago-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('imago-bootstrap-css'), '1.0.0' );

    wp_style_add_data( 'imago-theme-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'imago-bootstrap-popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array(), null, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'imago-bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), null, true );

    //wp_enqueue_script( 'imago-bootstrap-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), null, true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imago_theme_scripts' );
```

I still tried this way by replacing the `popper.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` script with:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'imago-bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), null, true );`, but unfortunately that doesn't change anything either. Navigation in the mobile version still doesn't work.

The directory structure is preserved correctly.
In the first configuration you can see that the `popper.min.js' file is plugged before the 'bootstrap.min.js' file according to the documntation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They may not be working because you're not including jQuery to the dependencies.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'imago-bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
```

Other than that, they are loading, your nav console indicates that... ...are there any errors in the console?